# interpretation of integrating a Vector field on a curve

Tags: integration

My textbook contains the formula (where * means dot product):
$$\int_CF*dr=\int_C(f(x,y)i+g(x,y)j)*(dxi +dyj)=\int_Cf(x,y)dx+g(x,y)dy$$
My question is: is there a straightforward geometric interpretation of the sum of the line integral with respect to x summed with the one w.r.t. y?

I think of the line integral w.r.t. x as the area underneath a function when it is projected onto the x-axis, like this: 
[image]

Is there a similar interpretation of the line integrals of a vector field integrated w.r.t. x and y summed (apart from the obvious interpretation as the sum of those two areas)?

Comment: Check out [this animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#/media/File:Line_integral_of_vector_field.gif) from Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you. That helps. It is still hard for me to picture it though. As a start, is it correct that if the line over which is integrated is at every point tangent to the field then we are simply integrating the length of vectors in the vector field over the line, like this $$\int_C||F||ds$$, where  $ ds =\sqrt{(dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2)}$?